# Load SQL Server CE database into memory

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have an application where I need to query a SQL Server CE database multiple times, often for the same data. The database has many tables, with intention to increase the amount of tables in the future, so nothing fixed.

The process is very slow, so I need a way of dumping the whole database into memory, and performing the queries there. The queries are all going to be very simple (on par with get the record with id X from table Y).

I was considering a `DataTable`, but I have many tables so that won't work.

I was also considering using LINQ , but each table is very different and I don't want to handwrite a new object each time (and `.dbml` files won't work with SQL Server CE - go figure).

Any other solution?

Comment: Please provide some examples to help prop up this question. I nearly VTC as *too localized*, but I think with some work this could be a good question.

Comment: What sort of examples? The general question (dumping a whole sqlce database into memory so it works faster) isn't too narrow in scope in my opinion.

Comment: In that case I think it fits better at DBA.SE, since this is a sever-level optimization. The question is essentially, *how can I make SQL Server CE cache results in memory*.

Comment: Not really, the reason its taking so long is because I'm making (say) 1000 queries, and each one involves opening a connection, doing the query, closing the connection and repeat. I wanted a C#-level optimisation.

Comment: Keepp the connection open for the lifetime of your app, and use indexes - I think you are using the database the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way I ended up solving it is as follows.

I keep a Dictionary which maps tablenames to DataTables.

Whenever I try to access the DataTable, I search whether the name is in the dictionary or not.

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string tableName)
    {
            lock (lockMe)

            {
                    if (!dictionary.Keys.Contains(tableName))
                    {
                        ReadTableIntoMemory(tableName);
                    }

                   return dictionary[tableName];
            }

    }
```

If they are not there, I lazily read the entire table into memory (using select * and a datatable) and add it to the dictionary.

This solution works for my case, but it might be too specific as a general solution.

Comment: This isn't thread-safe. If you're taking this approach you should be using a `Lazy<T>`

Comment: Oh right. My functionality doesn't require thread-safety, but I'll edit the answer for posterity.

Comment: This also doesn't handle updates or deletions. If those never happen, why are you using a `DataTable` at all? Why not just load everything into a dictionary at the start?